# Facebook SDK, function is getting called twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to implement facebook login button in my website, so far everything is going good but I'm stuck in a situation.
I have this facebook sdk js:

```
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      getUser();
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';}
      }
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXX',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
      status     : true,  // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function getUser() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=email,name,birthday,gender', function(response) { 
      var ufd=JSON.stringify(response);
        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/fb-callback.php",
      data: {ud:ufd},
      success: function(msg) {
    if(msg!=""){
      alert("Successfully Logged In !"+msg);
    }
    else{
    alert("Some Error");
    }
 }
});  
    });
  }
```

In getUser() function ajax is being called twice or the function getUser() itself is getting called twice.
I searched for many answers but nothing is relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is already logged in to your App with Facebook then, `statusChangeCallback(response)` will be called once due to the following block in the `window.fbAsyncInit`

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});
```

Now when you login with the Facebook Login button on your page, then `checkLoginState()` will be called and again call the `statusChangeCallback(response)` method and hence you see your ajax call triggered twice. To solve this you can do either of the following

1. Hide the Login button if the `response.status === 'connected'` i.e. the user is automatically logged in.
2. Remove the `FB.getLoginStatus` check from the init and ask the user to login to your app by clicking the login button on every first visit to your page.

Comment: @Rahul hello Rahul, would you be kind enough to let us know what did you change? I don't have it in the init block, still it's getting called twice. What else did you change?

Answer (score 0):

in getUser function there are two functions are there which will trigger ajax request first one `FB.api('/me?fields=email,name,b` and other one the callback function

`var ufd=JSON.stringify(response);
        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",`

so obviously it will initiate two ajax requests

Comment: braces are correct and 'checkLoginState' is outside the 'statusChangeCallback()' .

Comment: yeah, I didn't see it anyway if it initiating double ajax requests its coz there are function calls which are responsible for two ajax requests in the getUser function itself nothing abnormal try calling the Fb.API directly `FB.api('/me?fields=email,name,birthday,gender', function(response) {});` in console